# PN532 write data to Mifare card

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I want to write data to a MIFARE Classic card. But I don't know which address can be written. I just know that sector 0 can not be written.
Could anyone show me the complete address map that can be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the manufacturer block (block 0), all other blocks on MIFARE Classic cards can be written (after proper authentication and unless they have been permanently write-protected by setting the sector's access bits).

So for a MIFARE Classic 1k card, blocks 1 to 63 can typically be written (with the above mentioned exceptions). You can find the datasheet with the complete memory layout and explanation of access bits [here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S503x.pdf).

Similarly for a MIFARE Classic 4k card, blocks 1 to 255 can typically be written (with the above mentioned exceptions). You can find the datasheet with the complete memory layout and explanation of access bits [here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S703x.pdf).

Comment: Yes,I find it.Thanks very much. Write the command to 3nd block,ues the keyA or kyeB to Authorize,and then we can write it in the block that we need.